# query with dynamic selectionArgs android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I am trying to return a cursor with all the rows which match one of the id's in the String Array ids - This is what I have so far I am getting the error below. I am thinking it has something to do with the fact it has only 1 '?' but how do I then make this dynamic? Any suggestions?

```
public Cursor getSelectedEntries(String... ids)
{

    return movieDbInstance.query(
            DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[]{_ID, MOVIE_ID, MOVIE_TITLE, MOVIE_YEAR, MOVIE_POSTER},
                MOVIE_ID + " = ?",
            ids,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}
```

The String array has a changing number of ids for example 
it could be {"abc","def"} or it could be {"abc","def","gef","gdf"} and I need to return all rows where the MOVIE_ID = one of them...

Error Message`**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 10 because the index is out of range.

The statement has 1 parameters. at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of ids, but have only one placeholder in your WHERE-Statement. If you have several ids, you need to put several placeholders in the WHERE-clause like:

```
MOVIE_ID + " = ? OR " + MOVIE_ID + " = ? OR " + ...
```

The number of placeholders of course needs to match the number of ids in you array. So if the number of ids changes, you need to construct your WHERE clause dynamically like above.